# With Jquery UI Dialog, I want to know ok button selected or cancel button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Im tring to use JQUERY UI but I have a problem. I want to get the button selected in the dialog box and then do something in my page. these are the codes I use to generate the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            // Dialog
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 300,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            // Dialog Link
            $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="dialog_link">Open Dialog</a>
    <!-- ui-dialog -->
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the "something" you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow each of your `$(this).dialog("close");` lines with a call to a function relevant to the button. You have the dialog close line twice, once for each button so each can be followed by a different function call.

Answer (score -1):

Well jQuery takes care of knowing what button has been pressed for you, basically. So during creation of the dialog is where you specify what action is to be executed on each button's clicked event.

You can call a specific function or write code lines directly, like so:

```
buttons: {
    "Ok": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log("Inline code example");
        myOkFunction();
    },
    "Cancel": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        myCancelFunction();
    }
}

function myOkFunction(){
    //Something that will happen on "Ok" button clicked.
}

function myCancelFunction(){
    //Something that will happen on "Cancel" button clicked.
}
```

You can, however change the code to be executed, during execution, by calling the widget options like so:

```
$(yourDialog).dialog("option","buttons",{
    "Ok":function(){
        var i = 0; //Inline code example
        this.Dialog("close");
        myNewOkFunction();    
    }
});
```

Be wary however that this will override all buttons in your dialog, so if you have more than one, you need to re-write them all.